# railsのdeviceでログインが必要なページの場合に登録ページに飛ばす方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

railsのdeviceでログインが必要なページの場合に登録ページに飛ばす方法を教えて下さい。

デフォルトではログインページ(new_user_session)に飛んでしまいますが登録ページ(new_user_registration)へ誘導するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

### `authenticate_user!`の動作をカスタマイズする方法

deviseのドキュメントにある[How To: Redirect to a specific page when the user can not be authenticated](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated)のとおり、`Devise::FailureApp`を継承したクラスで`redirect_url`をオーバーライドすることでリダイレクト先を変更できます。

### アドホックな方法

デフォルトの`authenticate_user!`を使わずに、

```
before_action :authenticate

def authenticate
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url unless user_signed_in?
end
```

としてリダイレクトするのが手っ取り早いでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

`new_user_session`の内で登録できるようにするか、`new_user_session`でなんらかの判定をして`new_user_registration`にredirectすればよいのではないでしょうか？